# Using swap(_:_:) with two different types

Tags: ios, swift, swap

I currently have my main view setup where when I tap a `UILabel`, it changes its' opacity to 0 and a text field, which was initially hidden and had its' opacity set to 0 appears with the aforementioned values inverted (`hidden = false, opacity = 1`).

I plan to swap the values between these two views often so I thought it would be ideal to use the `swap(_:_:)` function. Unfortunately I get this error being that `UILabel` and `UITextField` aren't the same type:

`Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField!' to expected argument type 'UILabel'`

Is there any way around this or will I be stuck creating my own function?

```
@IBAction func onTapToEnterBillAmount(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        swap(&self.tapToEnterBillAmountLabel, &self.billAmountTextField)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `swap(_:_:)` requires both arguments to be of the same type, try swapping the actual matching properties of the `UIButton`/`UILabel`:

```
@IBAction func onTapToEnterBillAmount(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        swap(&self.tapToEnterBillAmountLabel.alpha, &self.billAmountTextField.alpha)
    }, completion: { _ in
        swap(&self.tapToEnterBillAmountLabel.isHidden, &self.billAmountTextField.isHidden)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to work for `alpha` but not for `isHidden` for some strange reason. Any idea on why?

Comment: @CarlEdwards `isHidden` might not be animatable. I would just stick with `alpha`, or do the `isHidden` swap inside the `completion:` of `UIView.animate`

Comment: After looking through a few threads I think you're right. I can mark this correct but it also might help others by noting our discovery in your answer. Thanks again for your help.